# Why am I keep getting INTERNAL ERROR 500 with my firebase cloud function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, serverless

I was trying to deploy a cloud function on firebase but I keep getting this error. I deleted all of my logic to console the response and debug but nothing's changed.

I am sure that the problem is not related to permissions because the invocation is allowed for unauthenticated users.

this is the block of my function:

```js
// Firebase config
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const cors = require("cors")({
  origin: true
});

admin.initializeApp();

exports.emailMessage = functions.https.onCall((req, res) => {
  return cors(req, res, async() => {
    console.log(req);
    console.log(res);
  }).catch(() => {
    res.status(500).send("error");
  });
});
```

Comment: Currently when you catch an exception, it looks like you're sending the 500 response but without logging the exception at all - that will make it much harder to understand what's going wrong. What happens if you remove your `catch` call entirely? (I'd expect you to still get a 500 response, but for your logs to contain useful information.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I am having a problem with the set up and the docs are not helping

Comment: Well I've suggested that you remove the `catch` call (that's losing information for you), and then look at the logs.